# Ajaxifying vote creation which "POSTs" through member route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a polymorphic vote model which is called via a member route "POST" on 3 different models. In each of the parent models below (routes.rb), I have a vote method in each of the corresponding controllers which passes in the correct paramaters to create a vote for that model.

This is a similar implementation of the **from-scratch** rating system shown in Ryan Bates Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system

This all works nicely however I would like to Ajaxify the creation of a vote.

How can I do this when a vote is created by posting to the vote_object_path as per below? I have tried a jQuery function to post the form however it errors out asking for a create/vote template and I would like to retain the simplicity of this implementation if possible.

```
<div class="vote">
  <b>Votes: <%= answer.votes_count %></b><br>
  <%= link_to "up", vote_answer_path(answer, value: 1), method: "post" %>
 <%= link_to "down", vote_answer_path(answer, value: -1), method: "post" %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :questions do
     resources :comments, except: [:edit, :update]
     member { post :vote }
   end

  resources :comments do 
    member { post :vote }
  end 

  resources :answers do 
    member { post :vote }
  end
```

**answers_controller.rb**

```
def vote 
    @vote = current_user.votes.build(value: params[:value], votable_id: params[:id], votable_type: "Answer")
    respond_to do |format|
    if @vote.save
      format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "Vote submitted"}
      format.js
    else
      format.html {redirect_to :back, alert: "You can't vote on your own content"}
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: do you have a `vote.js.erb` template?

Comment: i dont have any templates/partials for votes either in a votes folder or one of the parent model view folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd suggest you is to bind the click from jQuery, POST query it, and update the HTML.

```
$('a.vote').click(function () {
  var url = this.href; // get URL link
  $.post(url);
});
```

Then, in a `vote.js.erb`

```
$('#vote_count').html("Votes: <%= current_user.votes %>");
```